# Popular Design Patterns for Web Application Components

Tags: oop, design-patterns, web-applications, web-application-design

I am preparing for a presentation on Design patterns in Web Application.
I know there is a discussion on the same [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications), But I guess it is more for a java web application. I wanted something more generic.

I have started listing some components need for a web application and associated design pattern.

- Request processing - Front controller pattern.
- Filters - Chain of responsibility (or Intercepting Filter in java world)
- Authentication and Authorisation components (ACLs based) - AOP pattern
- Logging component - AOP, Abstract Factory Patterns
- Exception Handling - Exception Shielding pattern
- Data layer (DB and Cache system) - DAO, Strategy, Singleton, Factory patterns
- Service Layer - Facade, Proxy, IoC patterns
- Presentation and processing - MVC pattern

It will be really helpful, if you could give some inputs for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those things are not *design* patterns. One source is [enterprise integration patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/), another is [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html).